# Product edit page problem in magento admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9

I am facing some weird problem , As I logged in to admin panel of magento everything works fine, except the product edit page. When I clicked on product to edit the details, it's load improperly for ref. please check image. I didn't get why this happening

[image]

Comment: any error in console or log?

Comment: No any errors in console

Comment: Enable developer mode and you will get the error on the page.

Comment: I got some error in system.log(Notice: Undefined index: _attribute_set  in /opt/eb-magento-rc1/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php on line 1407)

Comment: This is fixed. thanks @GopalPatel,@Jaimin Sutariya for help.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue. I have update the security page 1.9.3.4 to lastest all patch. Now i have faced the same edit page problem. i have enabled the devloper mode but no error log and also console.

Comment: i can't add the commands in above post. so i have posted.